# How to set value to asp:datagrid from child window?

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

Thanks that open this page:)

I'm new for asp and looking for the way to set some text values into cell of asp:datagrid.

I wanted to open a child window from datagrid which need to show some information.

but the problem is, I can't send some information from child window to parent window.

Its very simple if its just a form control.

I could use like

```
window.opener.document.getElementById("TextBox1").value = "value";
```

but I guess datagrid is more complicated...

If you have some tips for this, Please let me know.

thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0):

**[How to pass value from child window to parent window without refreshing the page using MasterPage](http://weblogs.asp.net/ssnair/archive/2010/05/16/how-to-pass-value-from-child-window-to-parent-window-without-refreshing-the-page-using-masterpage.aspx)**

**[This article explains basic options available to access the data present in a parent browser window from a child browser window or  vice versa.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25388/Accessing-parent-window-from-child-window-or-vice)**